# rosnode for creative interactive gesture camera

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use the interactive gesture camera but could not find any ros node written for the same. Is there some node for 'creative interactive gesture camera' available. ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62069/rosnode-for-creative-interactive-gesture-camera/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You mean the CREATIVE SENZ3D? I´m thinking on buying it instead of the ASUS Xtion, put looks like there´s a lot of work to do before making it work with ROS. Do someone have any additional information? It´s there at least a Linux driver? Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

I have verified that there´s a [Linux driver](http://www.softkinetic.com/AboutUs/NewsEvents/ArticleView/tabid/562/ArticleId/263/language/en-US/SoftKinetic-Releases-Linux-Ubuntu-Driver-for-DepthSense-Cameras.aspx). Also [PCL 1.7.1](http://2docs.pointclouds.org/news/2013/10/07/pcl-1.7.1-released/) support this camera. But I suppose we still need something to generate and publish sensor_msgs/Image and sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages.

**NEW UPDATE**

I'm using now this code (https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic) with the SENZ3D and all works fine.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2014-01-13**:
I have an experimental package that I am working on
https://github.com/scottmishra/creative_interactive_gesture_camera
that uses the drivers mention by jorge. Its not polished yet, but it does bring the Creative camera into ROS

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-01-13**:
Great news! Btw, can I ask you if you bought the camera from Intel (http://click.intel.com/) or directly from Creative? I want to buy one, but the comments about no warranty at all on Intel site scare me! Thanks

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2014-01-13**:
I'm not entirely sure, I came to my lab after the camera was already here. Though, I think the Creative uses the same sensors as the softkinectic cameras if that helps you at all.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-01-13**:
Anyway, I already ordered a camera. I'll give a try to your software when it comes (but will take a while). Thanks!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-01-20**:
Hello, I received the camera and started playing around. I compiled your driver but experienced a crash. Can I ask you what are your plans concerning the code? Will you actively develop it in the near future? Do you plan to create and publish a standalone driver node? Thank you a lot

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-02-26**:
Look forward to further development. By the way, have you made it working? @jorge?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-06-03**:
Hi, sorry of answering this 4 months later.... I suppose you already solved your issues, but I'm using now this code (https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic) with the SENZ3D and all works fine.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-07-06**:
@jorge, thank your for your answer, it is very useful and it is not late at all since I do not have time to solve it yet!

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-07**:
what is your experience so far with senz3d vs. kinect or asus xtion? @jorge

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-02**:
Does this work on Indigo? Does it require the Intel RealSense SDK? OpenCV also seems to have a driver, but it only works with an older Intel SDK that's no longer available.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2015-05-04**:
Hi, yes, it works on Indigo. You need to install the [DepthSense SDK Linux](http://www.softkinetic.com/language/fr-BE/Support/Download) before (and also opencv and pcl but rosdep will to if for you)

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-02-20**:
Hello! I am trying o use Creative Senz3D for BAxter and I am pretty much lost on how to install it. Can you please help me out with that? I have posted this as a question in http://answers.ros.org/question/255142/how-do-i-connect-creative-3dsenz-to-baxter-robot/